# Add XML Elements and Attributes dynamically

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting strucked in below concept. I am using .Net 2.0 Framework. How to achieve this using C# asp.net in .Net Framework

I have XML File in specified path and the xml is storing employee list in country wise. Like Below Structure. Need to add Employee Country Wise. Please As soon as possible..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EmployeeList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/format.xsd" key="lank">
  <Country id="**India**">
    <Emp Name="X1" address="Y1" id="Z1" />
    <Emp Name="X2" address="Y2" id="Z2" />
    <Emp Name="X3" address="Y3" id="Z3" />
  </Country> 
</EmployeeList>
```

If Country India is Exists then add records under specific country else add it as new country.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EmployeeList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/format.xsd" key="lank">
  <Country id="India">
     <Emp Name="X1" address="Y1" id="Z1" />
    <Emp Name="X2" address="Y2" id="Z2" />
    <Emp Name="X3" address="Y3" id="Z3" />
    <Emp Name="X4" address="Y3" id="Z4" />        <!-- Newly Added in existing Country -->
  </Country> 
</EmployeeList>
```

If New Country Come then Output needs to be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EmployeeList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/format.xsd" key="lank">
  <Country id="**India**">
     <Emp Name="X1" address="Y1" id="Z1" />
    <Emp Name="X2" address="Y2" id="Z2" />
    <Emp Name="X3" address="Y3" id="Z3" />  
  </Country> 
  <Country id="**USA**">
     <Emp Name="X4" address="Y3" id="Z4" />        <!-- Newly Added in seperate country-->
  </Country>  
</EmployeeList>
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a class

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the following code

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Name = "X4";
emp.Address = "Y3";
emp.Id = "Z4";
emp.Country = "India"; // or "USA"

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");

XmlNodeList countries = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
XmlElement country = null;

foreach (XmlElement temp in countries)
{
    if (temp.Attributes["id"].Value == "**" + emp.Country + "**")
    {
        country = temp;
        break;
    }
}

if (country == null)
{
    country = doc.CreateElement("Country", "http://tempuri.org/format.xsd");
    country.SetAttribute("id", "**" + emp.Country + "**");
}

XmlElement employee = doc.CreateElement("Emp", "http://tempuri.org/format.xsd");
employee.SetAttribute("Name", emp.Name);
employee.SetAttribute("address", emp.Address);
employee.SetAttribute("id", emp.Id);

country.AppendChild(employee);
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(country);
```

Answer (score 0):

I provided two method.  One by grouping countries then adding employees. Second adding new new employess to existing xml.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("address", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "India", "X1", "Y1", "Z1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "India", "X2", "Y2", "Z2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "India", "X3", "Y3", "Z3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "USA", "X4", "Y4", "Z4" });


            string identification =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<EmployeeList xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/format.xsd\" key=\"lank\">" +
                "</EmployeeList>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(identification);
            XElement employeelist = doc.Root;

            //method 1 by grouping countries
            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Country")).ToList();

            foreach (var rows in results)
            {
                XElement newCountry = new XElement("Country", new XAttribute("id",string.Format("**{0}**", rows.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Country"))));
                employeelist.Add(newCountry);
                foreach (DataRow employee in rows)
                {
                    newCountry.Add(new XElement("Emp", new XAttribute[] {
                        new XAttribute("Name", employee.Field<string>("Name")),
                        new XAttribute("address", employee.Field<string>("address")),
                        new XAttribute("id", employee.Field<string>("id"))
                    }));
                }
            }

            //method 2 by adding
            doc = XDocument.Parse(identification);
            employeelist = doc.Root;
            foreach (var employee in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                //test if country exists
                string countryName = string.Format("**{0}**", employee.Field<string>("Country"));
                XElement country = doc.Descendants("Country").Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == countryName).FirstOrDefault();
                if (country == null)
                {
                    country = new XElement("Country", new XAttribute("id", countryName));
                    employeelist.Add(country);
                }
                country.Add(new XElement("Emp", new XAttribute[] {
                    new XAttribute("Name", employee.Field<string>("Name")),
                    new XAttribute("address", employee.Field<string>("address")),
                    new XAttribute("id", employee.Field<string>("id"))
                }));

            }

        }
    }
}
​
```